# How do I run Spring Boot Tests on an existing Spring boot instance?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a reasonably complex application that I'm writing. It takes ages for the Spring Boot Tests to start an instance of Spring Boot and the application on a random port. Is there a way I can execute my tests on the existing "normal" running Spring Boot Application (locally), disabling the way the tests want to start their own test instance?

```
// This lot starts a new instance. Can't we use the existing running instance.
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class GraphQLTests {

    @Autowired
    private GraphQLTestTemplate graphQLTestTemplate;

    // Tests here...

}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but SpringBootTest should cache ApplicationContext, so it should not take much longer to run multiple tests than starting a local instance. Are you by any cache use dirtiesContext (which requires reinitialization of context)? Also what is your test doing, is it mocking beans, starting wiremock, or is it an E2E test, where you are only validating the response. Depending on what kind of test is it, it may or may not be possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: I know it is not what you ask but for example, in unit tests, the classes are created for each test method. I mean, if you have 5 tests in a class, there's 5 instance that's fired up. The reason is that no tests should depend on each other and they have to be in isolation. Therefore, in case of integration tests, I think it is logical to fire up new instance instead of using an existing one.

Comment: Yes, but also sort of, In this example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763066/how-to-test-an-aspect-with-springboottest/56764020#56764020 I did an example of starting a test Spring Boot App that has less stuff. You can do it with just the beans you want to. However, if auto-magic Spring jars are on the classpath, like security it can get really difficult and complex to provide everything needed to start. They would also make it slow to start. I usually use these test sparingly for these reasons.